# Shoes GUI toolkit per pixel manipulation possible?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

Is there any method for per pixel manipulation in the Shoes GUI toolkit? The manual is a tad bit suboptimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there is. Most elements accept a `:top` and `:right` that let you pick an offset per pixel, and lots of the drawing and shape stuff is per-pixel as well.

Comment: That's OK, but there is no element that can draw a 1x1 sized pixel. A one pixel length line (by parameters) will be 2 pixels wide, while a zero length line will not be drawn.