# Plotting individual pixel in shoes:Ruby

Tags: ruby, shoes

i am working with Shoes in Ruby. I could not find a method to plot individual pixels in the shoes window.... Can anyone help me??

:)

Comment: I have tried once as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981810/shoes-gui-toolkit-per-pixel-manipulation-possible

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. See [Shoes GUI toolkit per pixel manipulation possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981810/shoes-gui-toolkit-per-pixel-manipulation-possible)

I think the closest you can get is a 2x2 square:

```
Shoes.app do
  click{|b, x, y|
    rect(x,y,1,1) if b == 1
  }
end
```

Or a 2x1 line:

```
Shoes.app do
  click{|b, x, y|
    line(x,y,x+1,y) if b == 1
  }
end
```

Comment: Hey Simon.... Nice to see you again. :D. It's weird that pixel plotting is not possible in shoes. Can't we use the method shoes uses to draw lines in its window??  I mean... The lines are plotted by successively plotting pixels.... Can't we use the method it uses to draw lines??

Comment: @aayushshrestha Possibly, but it's not documented. If it can be done, you would need to take a look at the Shoes source and work out how to create a `pixel` method.

Answer (score 1):

That means that you can do something like that if you want to draw a pixel at x,y location, with a particular color assuming you know the background color:

```
def point(x,y,color, bg_color)
 stroke color
 line x,y,x,y+1
 stroke bg_color
 line x,y+1,x+1,y+1
end
Shoes.app do
 background white
 point 40,40,blue,white
end
```

:)

Of course for drawing pixels densely it is useless but in some application can be useful.